# how to insert space between individual digits in a file?

Tags: linux, sed

My data looks like:

```
$ cat input
1212103122
1233321212
0000022221
```

I want the output to look like:

```
$ cat output
1 2 1 2 1 0 3 1 2 2
1 2 3 3 3 2 1 2 1 2
0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 1
```

I tried:

```
sed -i 's// /g' input > output
```

but it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are:

```
sed 's/\(.\{1\}\)/\1 /g' input > output
```

And if you want to save the changes in-place:

```
sed -i 's/\(.\{1\}\)/\1 /g' input
```

### How it works:

`s/\(.\{1\}\)/\ /g` will add a space, after each 1 character.

For instance, if you wanted an output file like:

```
12 12 10 31 22
12 33 32 12 12
00 00 02 22 21
```

You could edit my answer to:

```
sed -i 's/\(.\{2\}\)/\1 /g'
```

So it will add a space, after each 2 characters.

In addition, `/\1 /` is the same as `/&`, and will add one white-space.
For instance, to add three: `/\1   /` or `/&   /`. You have many more options to use. Sed is a super-powerful tool.

**In addition** yes, as @Law29 mentioned, this will leave a space at the end of each line if you do not remove, so to remove them while adding spaces you can add a `s/ $//` to the end of given solution, to do so:

```
sed 's/./& /g; s/ $//'
```

I hope this could help.

Comment: Not `sed 's/\(.\{1\}\)/\1 /g'` ?

Comment: @tomas it is true . 3 should be chaged to 1

Comment: @zara yes you're right, I updated my post.

Comment: @tomas yes you're right, typo. I updated my post.

Comment: with `-r` you could remove most of the backslashes, making it more legible. `{1}` is not necessary, and if that is all you are matching then you don't even need to catch groups,

Comment: @Law29 I know what you say mate, just wanted to post an answer that may help the OP in other situations too, not only for this one!

Comment: Especially in that case it might be useful to elaborate a bit on how the solution works.

Comment: @ilkkachu Roger, I'm going to explain.

Comment: @ilkkachu Updated the answer mate, satisfied? ;)

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
sed 's/./& /g' input > output

$ cat input
1212103122
1233321212
0000022221

$ cat output
1 2 1 2 1 0 3 1 2 2 
1 2 3 3 3 2 1 2 1 2 
0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You have the `-i` option, which edits the file in place. This may have hindered you in finding the right solution.

Your problem is that you are trying to match an empty string, which `sed` will not allow. Instead, match any one character, and replace it with the same character followed by a space. This will leave you with a space at the end of each line, which you can remove with another sed.

```
$ cat input 
1212103122
1233321212
0000022221
$ sed -e 's/./& /g' -e 's/ $//' input > output
$ cat output
1 2 1 2 1 0 3 1 2 2
1 2 3 3 3 2 1 2 1 2
0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 1
$
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an `awk` option:

```
awk -F '' '{$1=$1}1' input > output
```

The principle of operation is:

- by setting an empty field separator `-F ''`, we split the input records (lines) into individual characters
- by evaluating `$1=$1` we force the record to be re-built with the default output field separator (which is a single space)
- `1` is true so print the result

A similar trick in perl:

```
perl -F'' -alne 'print join " ", @F' input > output
```

---

To illustrate:

```
$ awk -F '' '{$1=$1}1' input
1 2 1 2 1 0 3 1 2 2
1 2 3 3 3 2 1 2 1 2
0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 1
```